# Debug xml to postgres, a column myxml not exist?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    myxml    xml;
    datafile text := 'Questo PC/Documenti/ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;


CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
```

At the last line myxml gives an error the column not exists.

Comment: `unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) ` here `myxml` is variable from `f_sync_from_xml()`?..

Comment: I want a procedure to create a table from xml file but myxml gives an error the column not exists

Comment: so put it inside function?..

Comment: I declared a variable myxml...

Answer (score 2):

put statement inside the function body where you declare the variable `myxml`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sync_from_xml()
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    myxml    xml;
    datafile text := 'Questo PC/Documenti/ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

also - if you jsut create a table on each execution - second execution will give you error, that tble exists

you can use `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
t=# create temp table if not exists tmp as select now();
SELECT 1
Time: 57.280 ms
t=# create temp table if not exists tmp as select now();
NOTICE:  relation "tmp" already exists, skipping
CREATE TABLE AS
Time: 0.223 ms
```

Comment: How I create a table? I have to drop temp from the create table?

Comment: With if not exists give an error on as my code: CREATE TEMP TABLE if not exists tmp AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

Comment: maybe you have older version with create tem table AS not supported yet?..

Comment: pgadmin III is my version